# Does GMP serialize my multi-threaded code?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, gmp

I compute the pi number according to concurrent pi algorithm from [learning go](https://github.com/foamdino/learning-go/blob/master/concurrent-pi/concurrent-pi.go). Now what I do differently is split the amount of work in large blocks that are then calculated in parallel on 2 mapping threads (since my CPU has 2 cores). Their results are written to a queue that is frequently accessed by a reducing thread.

The **problem**: I also implemented a non-parallel version of the calculation which is actually **double** as quick as the multithreaded one! But since they both calculate the same result the work in the parallel version must actually be shared between the mapping threads.

The calculation code is equal in both versions:

```c
// this is called 6 times, with a block size of 1000000
void calcPiBlock(mpf_t result, uint32 start, uint32 end) { 
  // the precision is 64 bit
  mpf_t piItem; 
  mpf_init(piItem); 

  for (uint32 i = start; i < end; ++i) { 
    calcPiItem(piItem, i); 
    mpf_add(result, result, piItem); 
  }
} 

inline void calcPiItem(mpf_t piItem, uint32 index) { 
  mpf_t dividend; 
  mpf_t base; 
  mpf_init(dividend); 
  mpf_init_set_d(base, -1.0); 
  mpf_pow_ui(dividend, base, index); 

  mpf_t divisor; 
  mpf_init_set_d(divisor, 2.0); 
  mpf_mul_ui(divisor, divisor, index); 
  mpf_add_ui(divisor, divisor, 1); 

  mpf_div(piItem, dividend, divisor); 
  mpf_mul_ui(piItem, piItem, 4); 
}
```

With several printf statements I found out that the time used for synchronization in my parallel version is negligible in the total amount. Also switching off the reducing thread does not change the result (as expected).

Comment: So, where does your profiler say the time is spent?

Comment: Using mpf_pow_ui to compute (-1)^n? Aaaaaaaaaaaargh!

Comment: @MarcGlisse I do not have a profiler (Can you recommend one?). But judging from the printf statements that I inserted into the code by hand most of the time (95 % or so) must be spent in the two functions that are equal in the parallel and the non-parallel version of the program.